# Unable to run ionic3 application on iPhone

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

However, when I run `ionic serve` everything works properly.
I have just a couple of plugins listed below. I attempted to remove `firebase` and `network...` still the same issue.

```
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-firebase 1.0.0 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.19 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
```

Very unclear issue, how can I go about attempting to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: In what way did you create the build? Using XCode, Ionic, Cordova, what were the steps that you took?

Comment: Doesn't matter, if I run through `ionic Cordova run` or from Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else is using GSAP with Cordova please refer to this:
https://greensock.com/forums/topic/17961-draggable-crashing-ionic-2-cordova/

Fixed my issue.